# Setting up SMTP server in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, smtp

Done a lot of googling but all the info seems dated and refers to older versions of Windows

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8b83ac7t(v=vs.100).aspx

Can any Windows experts tell me how to set up an outgoing SMTP mail server in Windows 10?

Comment: It required third-party software.  The information you find is still relevant for Windows 10 though.

Comment: Check out https://www.hmailserver.com/ for a potential solution.